# How to use Javascript in Angular project

Tags: angular

I am a beginner. I'll do my best explaining my problem.

I am hoping to use the following plugin as a Select option in my project. The project is [found here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-select-option).

If you look at the documentation, They have refereed to the project as

```
<script src="<your-path>/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="<your-path>/angular/angular.js"></script> 
<script src="<your-path>/angular-select/src/angular-select.js"></script> 
angular.module('myApp', ['angular-select']);
```

In y project I need to declare this plugin as follows:

```
import {Select} from 'path to the project';
```

My question is how can I use the plugin and declare it in my project in the format `import {Select} from 'path to the project';` ?

Comment: Looks like you are mixing Angular and AngularJS.  Is that your intention?

Comment: No. I am using Angular5 in my project. Can  someone please help me out here. Can I still use this plugin ?

Comment: It may not be possible.  What is your use case? May be Angular has something equivalent

Comment: That plugin is for angularJS